# PHP/MySql Debugging an SQL query to add values to a database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this simple code where I am trying to have 3 fields, first name, last name, and email, tag to mysql database from a website form. When I test the form and hit "register"
the error comes up that "An Error Has Occured. The item was not added." How can I debug this, as I'm not sure what point the error is coming in?

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Nomad - New User Registration Results</title>
</head>

<body>
   <h1>Nomad - New User Registration Results</h1>
 <?php
 // create short variable names
 $First_Name=$_POST['First_Name'];
 $Last_Name=$_POST['Last_Name'];
 $Email=$_POST['Email'];
 if(!$First_Name || !$Last_Name || !$Email) {
 echo "You have not entered all the required details.<br />"
 ."Please go back and try again.";
 exit;
 }
 @ $db=new mysqli('localhost','nomad_steve','steven','nomad_prod');
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 echo "Error: Could not connect to database. Get it together Steve!";
 exit;
 }
 $query = "insert into nomad_prod values
      (' " .$First_Name.",' " .$Last_Name."',' ".$Email."')";
  $result=$db->query($query);
 if ($result) {
 echo $db->affected_rows." book inserted into database.";
  } else {
 echo "An Error Has Occured. The item was not added.";
  }
 $db->close();
 ?>
 </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: echo mysql_error() in else condition.

Comment: @TinkuRana I'm not sure what you mean here :/

Comment: mysql_error() will give you exact error in your query.

Comment: Try to echo  this in else condition `echo "Table creation failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error`;

Comment: In your case use  printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $db->error);

Comment: Ah that worked, it is error message 15. But when i google search that error message nothing comes up. Apologize for all the comments.

Comment: I think something is wrong with your db connection object

Comment: @Tornado Should I be using "localhost" if my SQL database is hosted through HostGator? Because I know my other info is correct

Comment: It's depends upon your hosting server.

Comment: @Tornado my table name within the database nomad_prod is called Player...does that have to be spelled out somewhere in the code?

Comment: `nomad_prod ` is your data base not your table in that db,what is your table name where you have to store your data

Comment: @Tornado Player (it is a table in the nomad_prod database)

Comment: @Stuave see my answer that should help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this may solve your problem

```
$query = "insert into Player(first_name,last_name,email) values('" .$First_Name."','".$Last_Name."','".$Email."')";
$result=$db->query($query);
```

I have checked and got it you have to specify your column name where you have to enter your data.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. I still get the same error message 15

Comment: Try to check your connection object ,It's seems like your are not connect to your database

Comment: But isnt the if(mysqli_connect_errno) checking to see if i can connect to the database? Since I pass that step in the code, isn't it an issue separate from my connection?

Answer (score 0):

```
(' " .$First_Name.",' " .$Last_Name."',' ".$Email."')";
```

You have missed the `'` after `First_name` in above query, it should be

```
(' " .$First_Name."',' " .$Last_Name."',' ".$Email."')";
```

Comment: That is true thank you for noticing that, but i fixed that and it still comes up with the same error.

Comment: Error Message 15 comes up but a google search for that gives me no relevant results

Answer (score 0):

Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead of building your query yourself.

You are duplicating $_POST['First_Name'] as $Email, that doesn't look right to me

Try making the changes above and see what comes up.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to admit that the above link does not make any sense to me :/..I am very new to this and am trying to learn quickly. I fixed that issue above about $Email that you mentioned though, but it still didnt fix the code.

Comment: prepared statements are used to prevent SQL injection and are supported by every client language I know of and are not used as widely as they ought to be.